# Optimal way to retrieve hub context in SignalR 3.0 from anywhere

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working on a Asp .NET 3.1 application using SignalR 3.0 and I need the ability to access the hubcontext at any time. I regularly and receiving data and processing it to push out to the clients when a timer event fires. This means I can rely on the ability to access the hubcontext when the client calls a hub method or through the controllers or middleware. Since I cannot use GlobalHost in this version of signalR, what is the optimum way to do this?

I have tried several different things, I originally thought to keep a static reference to the hubcontext but I don't think that is a very reliable method. I thought to keep a static reference to an `IServiceProvider`, but by the time my timers fired, the service provider had been disposed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using standard Asp.Net Core Dependency Injection (IServiceCollection) you can inject `IHubContext<ChatHub>` in constructor of your service:

```cs
    public class NotificationsHub : Hub
    {
    }

    public class NotificationService(IHubContext<NotificationsHub> notificationsHub) : INotificationService
    {
    }

    // ***** At Startup ********

    // SignalR registration
    private static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      app.UseSignalR(routes =>
      {
        routes.MapHub<NotificationsHub>(hubRoute);
      });
    }

    // dependencies registration
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddSingleton<INotificationsService, NotificationService>();
    }
```

Does it work for you ?

Comment: I believe that should work for me, but I'm not 100% sure. If I have dozens of instances of my class with a timer that may be created or need to be torn down at any time, will this satisfy that requirement? Forgive me for not being too sure how this works just yet :)

Comment: @SA3709, in the example the `INotificationsService` has registered as Singleton, that means only one instance exist and it should be fine (no performance overhead) if *I have dozens of instances of my class* which requires such dependency.

Comment: SignalR in .NET Core 3 is a transciente and not a singleton. You don't need to add it as a singleton to get the context.